# CodeIgniter not submitting form values to database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Setting the **"method" attribute of form** fixed this for me, everything is submitting to the database fine, now, I have a similar problem with my validating credentials but maybe it has the same root as this problem since I forgot about method in the first place, thank you all very much.

I have a problem while attempting to learn CodeIgniter and general MVC principles.

I have a sign up form view

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" style="width:500px;" action="sign_up">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Sign Up</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="input-xlarge" required="" type="text">
    <p class="help-block">Your username</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="email_address">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="email_address" name="email_address" placeholder="Email address " class="input-xlarge" required="" type="text">
    <p class="help-block">Enter your email address</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" class="input-xlarge" required="" type="text">
    <p class="help-block">Enter your first name</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" class="input-xlarge" type="text">
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="password">Password Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-xlarge" required="" type="password">
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="password">Password Confirmation</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password" class="input-xlarge" required="" type="password">
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit" >Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Which submits to (user/)sign_up

```
public function sign_up() {

     $this->load->model('login_model');
        if($query = $this->login_model->create_member()){
            $data['main_content'] = 'user_login_view';
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
            }

    }
```

And passes to the model function "create_member"

```
function create_member()
    {
        $newdata = array(
            'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name') 
            );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $newdata);
        return $insert;
    }
```

I *believe* I have the correct table set up and I am following the MVC principle.

```
id  int(11)         
user_name   varchar(25)         
password    varchar(32)         
email   varchar(50)         
first_name  varchar(32)         
last_name   varchar(32)
```

**My problem is the password is the only value that is passing over into the database for the rest it simply submits 0, any suggestions or obvious mistakes to point out?**

```
ID      user_name   password                        email first_name last_name
20      0       d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e    0   0   0
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you using ajax form submission? Try without `md5()` function and check the password value. Is it also value 0 for password?

Comment: have you checked in your console if you are really submitting the form. Open the console and check it.

Comment: Add method="post" to your form element, then print_r($data) before inserting. A useful snippet for debugging is make a test.php view and put this code inside : <pre><?php print_r($this->_ci_cached_vars); ?></pre>. Then sends your data to this view and you will see all vars

Comment: @Rahil You are correct, It's not submitting any value for the password field either, just as you say the md5 hash of 0. 

-Gytis Thank you that is a useful snippet, the array is empty except for the main_content variable which is working fine, so there is something wrong with my form then? 

I have not used code igniters built in form_open() function, but I do not HAVE it to use either, is that correct?

Comment: @Pheonix2105 are you using ajax form submission? If not why you don't have your `action` and `method` attributes.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 You do not HAVE to use the `form_open` function, but I generally find that using it is useful, especially from the standpoint of setting the right action on the form.

Comment: `form_open` should always be used! Using `form_open` function also prevent csrf attacks.

Comment: @RahilWazir only prevents CSRF attacks if you have `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in config.php

Comment: @Rahil I did not know that either, I will switch it to, form_open, thank you.  I cannot mark your answers as the correct one since they are comments.

Thank you everyone else for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change your form open tag to explicitly call the controller, and you need to include a `method="post"` attribute to get the form to post. E.g.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" style="width:500px;" action="/user/sign_up" method="post">
```

If you wanted to use CI's form helper, you could use the following:

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'style' => 'width:500px;');

echo form_open('user/sign_up', $attributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Var_dump on your post variables, you not getting any post variables and the only reason you think you are getting the password is because you running md5 on an empty string.